# Retrieving data from multiple columns from two tables using join in php, as per the info provided by user

Tags: php, mysql, forms, left-join

I'm trying to create a basic shipment tracking page for my courier company. The user will provide the reference number and the query is required to pull the data in different columns from two tables. Below is the HTML code and below that is the php code. The HTML works ok but when I submit the form, the php throws a blank page. Can anyone tell me what mistake I'm doing here. Thanks in advance for the help.

HTML Code:

```
<form action="tracking.php" method="POST" id="insert">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Please enter your 9 digit Docket No:</td>
<td><input type="text" size=9 name="docketno"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2 id="sub"><input type="submit"onClick="confSubmit(this.form);" name="submit" value="submit" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" value="Reset!"></td>
</tr></Table></form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

// contact to database

$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'userid', 'password') or die ("Error , check your server connection.");

mysql_select_db("testing", $connect);



//Get data in local variable

$_docketno=$_POST['docketno'];


// check for null values

if ($_docketno=="")

echo "Docket Number must be entered, please hit back button and re-enter Docket Number";

else{

$query = "SELECT shipment_data.docketno, shipment_data.bookingdatetime, shipment_data.customercode, shipment_data.shippername, shipment_data.bookingou, shipment_data.assureddeliverydate, for_delivery_details.deliverydatetime, for_delivery_details.deliverystatus, for_delivery_details.name_and_number_of_the_person_to_whom_del, for_delivery_details.deliveryattemptnumber_1, for_delivery_details.deliveryattemptnumber_2, for_delivery_details.deliveryattemptnumber_3, for_delivery_details.faileddel.attempt,reason_1, for_delivery_details.faileddel.attempt,reason_2, for_delivery_details.faileddel.attempt,reason_3 "
 "FROM shipment_data LEFT JOIN for_delivery_details where docketno=".$_POST['docketno'].
    "ON shipment_data.docketno = for_delivery_details.docketno"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out the contents of each row into a table 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo Docket Number          " - ". $row[docketno];  
    echo Booking Date Time          " - ". $row[bookingdatetime];
    echo Customer Code          " - ". $row[customercode];
    echo Shipper Name           " - ". $row[shippername];
    echo Booked From            " - ". $row[bookingou];
    echo Assured Delivery Date      " - ". $row[assureddeliverydate];
    echo Delivery Date Time         " - ". $row[deliverydatetime];
    echo Delivery Status            " - ". $row[deliverystatus];
    echo Name Number to whom delivered  " - ". $row[name_and_number_of_the_person_to_whom_del];
    echo First Delivery attempt date    " - ". $row[deliveryattemptnumber_1];
    echo Second Delivery attempt date   " - ". $row[deliveryattemptnumber_2];
    echo Third Delivery attempt date    " - ". $row[deliveryattemptnumber_3];
    echo First delivery, fail reason    " - ". $row[faileddel.attempt,reason_1];
    echo Second delivery, fail reason   " - ". $row[faileddel.attempt,reason_2];
    echo Third delivery, fail reason    " - ". $row[faileddel.attempt,reason_3];

}
?>
```

MySql tables:

```
create table if not exists `shipment_data` (
  `docketno` int(11) not null,
  `referenceno` int(11) default null,
  `bookingdatetime` datetime not null,
  `customercode` int(11) not null default '9999',
  `shippername` varchar(100) not null,
  `shipperaddress` varchar(255) not null,
  `shipperphone` varchar(12) not null comment 'no special characters like (,),+',
  `shipperemail` varchar(50) null default '@',
  `consigneename` varchar(100) not null,
  `consigneeaddress` varchar(255) not null,
  `consigneephone` varchar(12) not null comment 'no special characters like (,),+',
  `consigneeemail` varchar(50) null default '@',
  `bookingou` varchar(20) not null,
  `deliveryou` varchar(20) not null,
  `assureddeliverydate` date not null,
  `numberofpackages` int(9) not null default '1',
  `firststickernum` int(11) not null,
  `laststickernum` int(11) not null,
  `packagedetails` enum('documents','carton box','gunny bag','wooden box','plastic bag') not null,
  `goodstypecode` int(6) not null,
  `goodsdescription` varchar(255) not null,
  `goodsvalue` decimal(10,0) not null,
  `freestoragedays` smallint(6) not null default '1',
  `customerinvoiceno` varchar(100) default null,
  `waybillnumber` varchar(100) default null,
  `servicecode` varchar(255) not null,
  `servicedetails` varchar(255) not null,
  `riskcoverage` enum('shipper risk','carrier risk') not null,
  `length_inches` decimal(10,2) not null default '1.00',
  `breadth_inches` decimal(10,2) not null default '1.00',
  `height_inches` decimal(10,2) not null default '1.00',
  `volumetricweight` double not null comment '((length x breadth x height)/1728)x10',
  `actualweight_kg` decimal(10,2) not null default '0.10',
  `chargedweight_kg` decimal(10,2) not null default '0.10',
  `totalcharge` decimal(10,2) not null default '1.00',
  `arrivaldateatdel_ou` datetime default null,
  `movementstatus` enum('','in-transit','reached') default null,
  `movementid` varchar(75) default null,
  primary key (`docketno`)
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8;


create table if not exists `for_delivery` (
  `docketno` int(11) not null,
  `assureddeliverydate` date not null,
  `deliverydatetime` datetime null,
  `deliverystatus` enum('','taken for delivery','delivered','undelivered','partial delivery') not null,
  `undeliveredfor18hrs_reason` tinytext null,
  `adicode` varchar(20) not null,
  `adiname` varchar(100) not null,
  `adinumber` int(11) not null,
  `deliveryattemptnumber_1` datetime null,
  `faileddel_attempt_reason_1` varchar(255) null,
  `deliveryattemptnumber_2` datetime null,
  `faileddel_attempt_reason_2` varchar(255) null,
  `deliveryattemptnumber_3` datetime null,
  `faileddel_attempt_reason_3` varchar(255) null,
  `name_and_number_of_the_person_to_whom_del.` varchar(255) null,
  `if_not_the_named_person,_upload_copy_of_identity_proof` blob null,
  `first_noticedate` date null,
  `first_noticenum` int(11) null comment 'after non-delivery 6 days of arrival at ou',
  `second_noticedate` date null,
  `second_noticenum` int(11) null comment 'after non-delivery 15 days of arrival at ou',
  `third_noticedate` date null,
  `third_noticenum` int(11) null comment 'for auction/disposal intimation after non-delivery 30 days of arrival at ou',
  primary key(docketno),
  foreign key (docketno) references shipment_data(docketno) on delete cascade
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8;
```

Comment: What is the problem? An error or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($_POST['docketno'] == ""){

   echo "Docket Number must be entered, please hit back button and re-enter Docket Number";
}

else{

   $query = "SELECT * FROM shipment_data LEFT JOIN for_delivery_details ON shipment_data.docketno = for_delivery_details.docketno where docketno=".$_POST['docketno']; 

   $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

   // Print out the contents of each row into a table 
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
       echo "Docket Number           - ". $row[docketno];  
       echo "Booking Date Time           - ". $row[bookingdatetime];
       echo "Customer Code           - ". $row[customercode];
       echo "Shipper Name            - ". $row[shippername];
       echo "Booked From             - ". $row[bookingou];
       echo "Assured Delivery Date       - ". $row[assureddeliverydate];
       echo "Delivery Date Time          - ". $row[deliverydatetime];
       echo "Delivery Status             - ". $row[deliverystatus];
       echo "Name Number to whom delivered   - ". $row[name_and_number_of_the_person_to_whom_del];
       echo "First Delivery attempt date     - ". $row[deliveryattemptnumber_1];
       echo "Second Delivery attempt date    - ". $row[deliveryattemptnumber_2];
       echo "Third Delivery attempt date     - ". $row[deliveryattemptnumber_3];
       echo "First delivery, fail reason     - ". $row[faileddel.attempt,reason_1];
       echo "Second delivery, fail reason    - ". $row[faileddel.attempt,reason_2];
       echo "Third delivery, fail reason     - ". $row[faileddel.attempt,reason_3];

    }
}
```

***Update:***

Method 1

```
echo "Docket Number           - ". $row[docketno] ."</br>";
```

use it in all echo statement same as like this.

method 2

Use HTML [table](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) tag to display in a table style.

Comment: Hi Ramesh, using your code the things seems to be working as it gives the message when I leave the space blank however I'm getting the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where docketno=123456789ON shipment_data.docketno = for_delivery.docketno' at line 1

Comment: I did, I placed them like this. <?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

// contact to database

$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'rajnikhil', 'ut-300r2u') or die ("Error , check your server connection.");

mysql_select_db("testing", $connect);

 

//Get data in local variable

$_docketno=$_POST['docketno'];
 

// check for null values

if ($_POST['docketno'] == ""){

that is in the first two lines after <?php, don't know if that is how I'm supposed to place it. If that's not correct please provide me with copy and pastable lines and the location in the code.

Comment: Can you place a screen shot or tables structure with sample data to your question.

Comment: I posted the structure of the two tables I'm trying to join.

Comment: Ok I got it working but the output comes up like a paragraph and not like a table. Any suggestions on how to improve the output statements?

Comment: @rajnikhil I just gave you a hint. Try it so you will find it work good.